# Database structure for voting of articles and comments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema, relational-database

I'm quite new to relational databases and web programming in general and I'm facing a problem on how to structure my database for use of a voting system, similar to reddit.

I'm using sqlalchemy, the important bits are shown below:

```
class Vote(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'votes'

    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    vote_type = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    user_id   = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    #article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article_items.id'))
    #comment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comments.id'))

class ArticleItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article_items'

    id         = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    vote_ups   = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    vote_downs = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    article    = relationship("Article",
                              uselist = False,
                              backref = 'article_item')
    comments   = relationship("Comment")
    votes      = relationship("Vote", cascade = "all")

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id      = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    data    = Column(Text, nullable = False)
    replies = relationship("Comment")

    vote_ups   = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    vote_downs = Column(Integer, default = 0)
    votes      = relationship("Vote", cascade = "all")

    parent_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comments.id'))
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article_items.id'))
```

As it stands now, I have to include two foreign keys in `class Vote`, but only one of the two keys is used at any time.

Is there any easier/recommended way to do this? Should I keep two different vote types instead; one for comments and one for articles? Or should I maybe merge `ArticleItem` and `Comment` into one `class Voteable`?

Comment: Take a look at [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) example.

Comment: That's a bit over my head unfortunately, I will try to read it more carefully. But, to my understanding, it keeps a `type` column instead and the relation is polymorphically handled; in the case of only two possible parents, isn't that the same as above?

Comment: It is not entirely the same. and in a way I like your code better compared to `generic_fk` recipe because you can enforce `ForeignKey` constraints. I do not think there is an easier way to do what you have done though. Maybe there is a *cleaner* way though.